# my sql fetch array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

i have a transaction database with the following fields

```
trans_id    prod_id
    1          1
    1          2
    1          3
    2          1
    2          3
```

i need this to be converted into array in which all the products belonging to same transaction will be in one array so i can do the processing for this im making use of the following code however it doesn't seem to work. I checked the the length of $value during iteration of the while loop it first shows 2 and then 2 again instead of 3 and 2
the entire code is like this

```
<?php

// MySQL Database Structure:  
// Name: tree
// Table: node
// Columns:id, parent, child


$con=mysql_CONNECT("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
 mysql_select_db("tree", $con);

 mysql_query("truncate table node");

 $sql="INSERT INTO node (data,parent) VALUES(0,0)"; //first insertion for the root node
 mysql_query($sql);
 $par1=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM node where data=0");
 $par=mysql_fetch_array($par1); 
 //echo $par['id'];
 $abc="";
 for($z=1;$z<=3;$z++)
 {
    $result= mysql_query("SELECT prod_id FROM user_prod WHERE trans_id=".$z);
    while($value=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $abc.=$value['prod_id'].',';
    }
    $abc=substr($abc,0,-1);
    $par=1;
    $list=explode(',',$abc);
    echo $list;
    $size=count($list);
    echo $size;
    for($i=0;$i<$size;i++)
    {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM node where parent=".$par;
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        $num=mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($num==0)
        {
            $x="INSERT INTO node (data,parent) VALUES ($list[$i],$par)";//new value at root
            mysql_query($x);
            $par1= mysql_query("SELECT id FROM node where data=$list[$i]");
            $par=mysql_fetch_array($par1);
        }
        else
        {
            while($x=mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                if($x['data']==$list[$i])
                {
                    $par1= mysql_query("SELECT id FROM node where data=$list[$i]");
                    $par=mysql_fetch_array($par1);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    $x="INSERT INTO node (data,parent) VALUES ($list[$i],$par[id])";//new value at root
                    mysql_query($x);
                    $par1= mysql_query("SELECT id FROM node where data=$list[$i]");
                    $par=mysql_fetch_array($par1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

$abc="";

}
mysql_close($con);


?>
```

errors

this code seems to be working fine however i keep getting this

```
error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_INC, expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\new_tree_sql.php on line 37
```

can anyone tell be how to get rid of it and wats the error all abt?????

Comment: You might be able to use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to do this.  It would be helpful if you indicated the data structure you want to receive, as it's not quite clear how you want to receive the data.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO i dint know about this thanx ill change them

Comment: @Am2292 - Do you mean that SELECT prod_id FROM user_prod GROUP BY trans_id works? And you just want to have an array from the resultset?

Comment: hey guys thanx for the help i fixed the problem this code works fine but there is this parse error i cannot understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does

```
$myArray[$value['trans_id']][] = $value['prod_id'];
```

Not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the function `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` , it is better than the `mysql_fetch_array` that is going to be deprecated according the features of php.

$query = "yourquery";

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

//get the associative array with mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["field"], $row["otherfield"]);
    }
```

and that is it

Comment: @Am2292 - it's like your variable $con.

Comment: its the connection... check this manual for more info http://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php